# Cast to ObjectId failed for value (reference to files)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

As the title says.

For more context : I have a small script (launched by php via exec) that will search for a chapter with a given id to do some changes on the images (scramble them) that I didn't manage to do in php (I'm newbie working with files).

here are my schema

```
//instantiate mongoose-gridfs
var gridfs = require('mongoose-gridfs')({
    collection:'files',
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
});

//Files = gridfs.model;
var FilesSchema = gridfs.schema;

FilesSchema.add({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    mime: String,
    filename: String,
    type: String
});

Files = mongoose.model('Files', FilesSchema);

var pageSchema = Schema({
    order: Number,
    image: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Files' },
    scrambled: Boolean
});

var ChapterSchema = Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    pages: [pageSchema]
});

var Chapter = mongoose.model('Chapter', ChapterSchema, "Chapter");
```

When I do that

```
Chapter.findById(chapterId)
        .populate('pages.image')
        exec(...
```

It raises the CastError : `{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "DBRef ...`
The error object is long, so I don't paste it here
but here is a pastebin with the full error message/object

```
https://pastebin.com/8n54Dhzt
```

If I chan,ge the type of Image to Array I can access the properties I need after, but in that case I can't reset the images properly (it writes an array on db instead of a Ref)

My ref is in an embeddedDocument, like that

```
Chapter.pages[0].image
```

image is the property that have the ref.

I don't really understand why I have this error, I followed the docs for the refs/populate : `http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html`

PS : A detail that can be important, The Reference is saved by DoctrineODM.
I use my node script to modify/encrypt the image, and then revert the encryption in js on my app.

PS2: sorry if a similar question is already posted and answered, there is so much post with the same error 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value' I admit I didn't read all of them, but those I read didn't help me.

EDIT : Update my code to use mongoose-gridfs Model instead of a different one + use subDocument instead of Array of object

Answer (score 0):

Well that seems an error with `chapterId`value. When you use `collection.findById`,  the passed value must pass the `ObjectId` criteria which is

1. 12-byte structure, the first 4 bytes of the ObjectId represent the
   time in seconds since the UNIX epoch.
2. The next 3 bytes of the ObjectId represent the machine identifier.
3. The next 2 bytes of the ObjectId represent the process ID.
4. And the last 3 bytes of the ObjectId represent a random counter
   value.

And if your passed id is not constructable to the pattern mentioned above this is definitely gonna throw the errors like you're getting.

So make sure you `chapterId` is correct or it is the same what you are getting from the database

Comment: I thought it was more about the pages.imageReference.
Like I said, if I change the reference (type ObjectId) of page.image to Array, it works, and I can have some info, but that's not what I want., I want a ref to change it at the end of my script. I'll take a look at the chapter Id anyway (maybe i made an error on my latests try)

Comment: Yeah I copy the chapterId from database when I launch via CLI with parameters, it's the same as the one in db.
The problem seems to be related to the population of the pages.image reference